# How to an IF BLANK Render blank ELSE render E71 in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to make an "if, then" in Google sheets.
If E8 Blank, render blank, else render E71
`=IF(ISBLANK(E8);"";blank),IF(COUNTA(E8);(E71))`

Answer (score 1):

This should be very simple! This is all you need:

`=IF(ISBLANK(E8),"", E71)`

When you do an `IF` statement...

- The first paramater is the condition, i.e the `IF`
- The second paramter is the `THEN`
- The third paramater is the `ELSE`